# Names for different forms of "command" sentences and their parts

Tags: expressions, terminology, syntactic-analysis

Edit: I'm rewording the question, so as to maybe make it more answerable.

My goal:  I'd like to create a parser that allows my program to accept certain types of english sentences.  In particular, I have modeled a world in which the user may interact with the contents of that world.

Instead of making up my own words, or using ugly descriptions, I'm trying to see if there is some existing academic agreement on the structures I'd like my program to understand.

I've narrowed it down to the following types of sentences, though I'm not sure exactly what to call them.

One type is just a single verb.

```
"Look"
"Sleep"
"Wait"
```

The next type is "Do an action to something".

```
"Get the ball"
"Drop the ball"
"Eat the salad"
"Look at the flower in the vase"
```

Notice that I'm allowing the "something" to be related to something else (eg, "the flower in the vase" as opposed to any other flower.)

The next group is "Do an action which involves a thing, and a location"

```
"Put the flower in the vase"
"Throw the ball to the boy"
"Get the food from the plate"
```

Of note here is the phrase "the flower in the vase" breaks down differently if it has "put" before it, than when it had "look" before it.  Not sure if there is a way to describe that.

Edit note: I had a final group here, but I realized I don't need help naming it, and it wasn't a complete description either.

Comment: This should be transferred to ELL.SU. There are simply too many incorrect presuppositions here to deal with.

Comment: @JohnLawler Can you be more specific?  It is a "Linguistics" question. Specifically, the structure of these various groups of sentences.  If you disagree with my grouping, please let me know what mistake I've made.

Comment: These are all different kinds of basic sentence structures that don't have anything to do with imperatives. They're all mixed up together without much in the way of context, and with a lot of confused and incorrect analyses. Start with basic syntax instead of trying to invent your own linguistics.

Comment: Well, I may have used the wrong term (imperative).  Really, what I'm trying to do is design an input system for a video game.  I'm trying to become unconfused, so if you could help, I'd appreciate it.   I'm modeling a world, and I want the user of my system to be able to tell his avatar in the world what to do and how to interact with it.

Comment: To put it another way, what could I do to make this question better?

Comment: Well, that's helpful information, though it's probly off-topic here. Are you intending to just let players type in commands, like Adventure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24483/discussion-between-daniel-and-john-lawler).

Comment: [Zork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zork) was able to parse sentences like this 25 years ago. You might want to do research on how it worked.